# Inspecting Firefox's Addon Panels

Tags: html, css, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm porting over a chrome extension to Firefox and need to refactor some of the css and html. I can't figure out a way to inspect the [Panel](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/panel.html) though. Is there a way to do it, or is the only way trial and error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to inspect panels as they are. An somewhat-effective workaround could be to open your panel's html file in a tab in Firefox and use the responsive design view to view the panel at the intended size:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View

This problem is being worked on, here is a somewhat-related bug:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=950936